# Why is the move constructor only called when there is already an element in the vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, back, emplace

I am trying to learn the new features in C++11. And I am testing the following code in XCode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class CClass
{
    std::string s;
public:
    CClass()
    {
        std::cout<<"Default Constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    CClass(const std::string v) :s(v) {
        std::cout<<"Constructor"<<std::endl;
    }

    CClass(const CClass& other): s(other.s) {
        std::cout<<"Copy Constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    CClass(CClass&& a) noexcept
    {
        std::cout<<"Move Constructor"<<std::endl;
        s = std::move(a.s);
    }
    CClass& operator = (const CClass& other)noexcept
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy Assignment"<<std::endl;
        if(this != &other)
        {
            s = other.s;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    CClass& operator = (CClass&& other) noexcept
    {
        std::cout<<"Move Assignment"<<std::endl;
        if(this != &other)
        {
            s = std::move(other.s);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<CClass> v;
    CClass x("hello");
    //v.push_back(x);
    std::cout<<"--------------------"<<std::endl;
    v.emplace_back("uiuiu");
    std::cout<<"--------------------"<<std::endl;
}
```

When I uncomment the push back I get the following result:

```
Constructor
Copy Constructor
--------------------
Constructor
Move Constructor
--------------------
```

Otherwise, if I comment it, I get:

```
Constructor
--------------------
Constructor
--------------------
```

My question is why is the move constructor not being called in second case? It is only being called in the first case when vector is initially not empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the one element in the vector needs to be moved to a new memory location. The reason why that happens is that the new size would exceed the vector capacity, so new memory with the new capacity had to be allocated for the vector.

From [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back):

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

The iterators and references are invalidated for the same reason: Because the elements are now stored in a new location in memory.

If you call `reserve` in the first case, you'll see that no move constructor is called:

```
CClass x{"hello"}; // constructor
v.reserve(2); // make space for 2 elements (you could have also used resize)
v.push_back(x); // copy constructor
v.emplace_back("uiuiu"); // constructor
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I believed vector was constructed with an initial capacity of 2. But this is new for me.

Comment: @akhileshzmishra If you don't say that you need space for 2 elements, you will not get it :) That's one of the advantages of C++: You don't pay for what you don't use/want.

Comment: If you add a move constructor that can move a string into your class `CClass` then can also avoid the copy constructor. For example by adding:

`CClass(std::string && v) :s(std::move(v)) {
        cout<<"move string into Constructor"<<endl;
}`

Comment: @snow_abstraction Why though? The copy constructor is called because a `CClass` instance is passed, not a temporary `std::string`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Due to how `emplace_back` forwards the arguments to the constructor of `CClass` instead of constructing a `CClass` with the arguments and then copying the constructed `CClass'. The end of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcgqUb1SXPk offers some explanation.

Comment: @snow_abstraction Oh you're taking about `emplace_back`! Then it makes sense, I thought you were talking about `push_back` :). But then you avoid the *constructor*, not the copy ctor. In that case however I would pass by value and move instead, so I don't have to maintain 2 ctors. :)